# Manipulação de scroll em Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-8

Estou desenvolvendo um componente no Angular versão 8 e na parte html do componente estou utilizando a seguinte navbar: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/kl8Q3 porém quando tento incorporar o javascript no meu componente não consigo implementá-lo no typescript.

Após fazer pesquisas sobre como "converter" o js para typescrip encontrei exemplos obsoletos que não funcionaram. Tenho pouco conhecimento em Angular e não tenho noção de como prosseguir com a solução desse problema. Segue abaixo o código que pretendo utilizar:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
                  $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
            });
      });

      // Scrolling Effect

      $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                  $('nav').addClass('black');
            }

            else {
                  $('nav').removeClass('black');
            }
      })
```

Comment: Qual erro você está recebendo ? Não precisa instalar a lib de tipos do jquery ? `npm i -D @types/jquery`

Comment: Não recebo erro. Esse código javascript não funciona na minha aplicação angular. Sabe aonde ele deve ser colocado?

Comment: Você pode tentar colocá-lo no `ngOnInit()` do seu componente navbar.

Answer (score 1):

A solução que encontrei foi essa

Typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  @ViewChild('nav', {static: true}) myNav:ElementRef;

  @HostListener('window:scroll') onWindowScroll() {
    if (window.scrollY > 1.5) { 
      this.myNav.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#808080';
    } else {
      this.myNav.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      this.myNav.nativeElement.classList.remove("background-color");
    }
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<nav #nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
```